# Good alternatives for middle mouse pan button?

Tags: shortcut

I've done a few meshes but am still relatively new to Blender. Does anyone use any alternative keys for panning that **isn't** the middle mouse button? I'm an artist so my hand/wrist is janky enough, but I can tell having to hold down the middle mouse key puts a lot of strain on it. (I also know Blender has a TON of commands- I wouldn't want to accidentally screw one up by binding the pan tool to it).

Comment: Hi prince. Have you found a better solution than the one provided which involves too many keyboard interactions? I would prefer to use right mouse button long-press to orbit as it is the case in many other 3d programs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Emulate 3 button mouse" option.

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> to pan.

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> to move.

This option is in the *input* part in the *preferences* and is generally used for touchpads.

In 2.79:

[image]

In 2.8:

[image]

This option has a little incidence. As <kbd>Alt</kbd> is dedicated to that, even outside of the 3D View (in panels), you can not use it for some other operations, like Alt+Clicking a button (which in some case allows to set a value for multiple objects).

Answer (score 0):

Use your numpad arrows, "8, 6, 2, and 4" to orbit, or hold Ctrl while using them to pan around.